# How to transition from battery to USB in a microcontroller?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

I am designing a 3V battery-powered simple micro-controller to collect sensor data in RAM. How can I avoid a conflict with the 5V of a USB when it comes time to upload the data? Disconnecting the battery would lose the RAM. The solution needs to be very simple as the PCB is very small.

Comment: Are you trying to manage both 5V and 3V supplies such that it will not affect your system. What type of micro controller are using? Please add additional detail.

Comment: I am powering a PIC with a 3V battery but then have to attach to 5V USB to get data.

Comment: What type of PIC?

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible options based on the limited infomation you have provided

1. Consider storing data in Non-Volatile Memory.
2. Use a LDO such as TPS73633 that can support wide input voltage range TPS73633 support a range of 3.5V and 5.5V. The output is 3.3V. An provide both the supply voltage options.

[image]

Comment: Non-volatile won't work for me. The LDO does not solve my problem.

Comment: @JimLewis Why will Non-volatile memory not work. Why does a LDO not solve the problem,

Comment: Because I need 16kb and don't want an extra chip. Where is the 3V battery and 5V USB in your LDO circuit?

Comment: With a couple of diodes to prevent backflow you can connect both the power sources to the +vbus

Comment: Yes that might do the trick though the drop from 3V might be pushing limits. And I suppose I don't need a diode on the higher 5V supply.

Comment: Why don't you select a micro controller that has non-volatile memory?

Comment: You will have design connector inputs for both 3V Battery and 5V USB supply. I just gave you an ideas. Take look at schematics from MSP430 launch pad or TIVA Launch pad for more details.

Comment: Because I could not find an economical one with 16kb of NVM.